Pipeline build runs summary for given Agent vs. Detailed build view results inconsistency
I just noticed on freshly created build machine, that some build results give different status depending on from what place I'm watching the build.
First view: specific agent build runs summarizing page
Second view: detailed view of given run.
Problem is that:
First view shows an exclamation mark on yellow background, meaning built has finished with some issues.
The same run when going into (Second view) shows "x" mark in red background, meaning this run has failed - which is true because some stages failed.
So my question is: why compact list of last runs shows yellow statuses (if failed indeed) for these runs instead of red? Is it somehow configurable ?
I have checked similar statuses on other build machines using the same pipeline configuration, and there was never a misleading status - if it was yellow on summary page, it was also yellow inside.
Except this one (newly configured) machine.
Agents used on "good" machines: 3.220.5, 3.225.0
Agent used on new machine: 3.236.1
=====
Update with some screenshots:

Entering into "First view"

Agent pool view
Specific agent build runs results list

Now entering into previously selected job - "Second view" to check what exactly "ended with issues":

Detailed job results view
I'm expecting these marks to be the same. Sometimes they are, sometimes they don't - idk the reason.
====

Can you share more screenshots about the page with the issue and share the pipeline definition sample? This will be helpful to understand this issue better.
